# Replacing data in an Excel table and saving the table

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I am trying to replace missing values in a table with the mean of the data. Code works but I cannot save the data in the table.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df1= pd.read_excel("sample.xlsx")
df1["Precio unitario promedio"].replace(np.NaN,mean)
```

When I run the code in `jupyter` the data is changed, but when I call the table again or try to print it, the missing values that were changed to the mean are returned as missing values. The table is not saved with the new values.

Comment: Please provide some sample data so we can recreate your problem, as well as what you expect the output to be.

Comment: You also need to write it to the file, not just replace it in pandas. You can use the `df1.to_excel()` function for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

```
df1 = df1["Precio unitario promedio"].replace(np.NaN,mean)
```

or:

```
df1["Precio unitario promedio"].replace(np.NaN,mean, inplace=True)
```